# draw mirrored javascript gauge

Tags: javascript, raphael, graphael, justgage

I need to create a gauge like the one in the image bellow.

[image: gauge]

I try to use the [JustGage](http://justgage.com) in order to make it, but I cannot find a way to render the down part of the gauge (red semi-circle in the image).

1. I'd like to use the JustGage. Does anybody know a way to draw a "mirrored" gauge using JustGage?
2. Is any other gauge capable to draw like in the image bellow?

Edit: css rotate doesn't help, because it reverses the drawing direction.

```
-ms-transform: rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform: rotate(180deg);
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/R4R3N/52/

Comment: It is an svg element, so you can add the `transform: rotate()` css attribute.

Comment: question updated. css rotate doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If CSS3 transforms are fine, you could Horizontally flip the gauge by using

```
-moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
-o-transform: scaleY(-1);
-webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
transform: scaleY(-1);
filter: FlipV;
-ms-filter: "FlipV";
```

I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R4R3N/53/).

Comment: Nice. But the text is still incorrect rendered. How do you rotate only the text?